# Merging two desktop systems (back)

Tags: home-directory, system

Maybe this question is a bit odd, but it puzzled me, and I don't know what to answer.

User copied his *home* folder from desktop to a new laptop some years ago. Now he want to dismiss one of computers (e.g. desktop) to use only one. What is the best way to merge the data, including apps' files and properties (e.g. messengers that keeps history only locally)?

What would happen if he restore backup of other system to the system he wants to keep?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rsync` from desktop (or its backup) to laptop with the `--ignore-existing` flag. This would copy data from the desktop to the laptop, but would not overwrite existing files.

Data which is only on the desktop will be made available on the laptop; program settings on the laptop will not be overwritten. There are two ways in which this would fail, slighly:

- when programs start to act differently when two configurations with different names are present. I can't think of such an application, but there may exist one. Those files should be removed by hand.
- in the case of programs like Thunderbird or Chrome, there would be two "default profiles", one of which would need to be made non-default manually.

For very important data, such cases should be considered on a program-by-program basis.

Comment: And what about snaps? I tried to dry run rsync and it  propose to copy a lot of snaps. And I'm pretty puzzled how to migrate them from another system when you have data in this snaps.